# Assume you have computed E{X} = 10

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let us denote by $\mathbb{E}[X]$ the expectation of a random variable $X$. Given no additional information, you are then asked to comment about the value of $\mathbb{E}[X^2 + X^4]$. Can you give a lower bound to 0.8$\mathbb{E}[X^2] + 0.2\mathbb{E}[X^4]$ in terms of $\mathbb{E}[X]$?

Comment: How are $X, X_{2}, X_{4}$ related?  If you meant $X^{2}$, etc., please typeset accordingly, before you get downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\{E(|X|)\} \leq \{E(|X|^s)\}^{1/s}, \,\, 1 <s<\infty$, which can be derived from the Holder's inequality by putting $Y=1$, and using $|E(X)|\leq E(|X|)$,

$$E(X^2)\geq E(|X|)^2 \geq |E(X)|^2 = 10^2$$

$$E(X^4) \geq E(|X|)^4 \geq |E(X)|^4 = 10^4$$

Take it from here.